# This RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted yet

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Rendom Forest for prediction

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
forest_clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(forest_clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3)
```

for y_train_pred system is showing 95% precision

I am using same model for actual prediction

```
test_stocks        = test_set.drop("is4PercPrft", axis=1)
test_stocks_labels = test_set["is4PercPrft"].copy()
test_prepared = full_pipeline.transform(test_stocks)
test_stocks_labels = test_stocks_labels.astype(np.uint8)
test_stocks_labels.value_counts()
```

for the below line I am getting error

```
final_predictions = forest_clf.predict(test_prepared)

This RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Comment: I don't see you fitting the model anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source code  of [`cross_val_predict`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L798), it would appear that the estimator is cloned when calculating the predictions in this method, and so `forest_clf` will not be fitted after running `cross_val_predict`.

You'll need to train the actual estimator used:

```
forest_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

before calling

```
final_predictions = forest_clf.predict(test_prepared)
```